# Pycharm Vagrant instance folder is not specified

Tags: python, pycharm, vagrant

Something really weird happened to my PyCharm+Vagrant setup. It errors out with the above message, although everything worked fine all the time and the instance folder is set correctly for sure.

So my theory is that something went wrong when I accidentally opened the project in PyCharm CE which doesn't have Vagrant support.

Since I read up on nearly every manual, help page etc. I am really sure it's not a configuration error on my side. I tried to remove the `.idea` directory for the project but that does not work either.